# There's any way to export data from Access to polygons without having UniqueIDs?

Tags: qgis, polygon, csv, ms-access, identify

I have polygons. I would need to have more information on them. I have that information in an Access database. But I don't have any identifier to serve as a reference. When I do a CSV import, it doesn't know which polygon has the information.

Is there any way to embed the information from the CSV in the polygons that I want?

Comment: If you have two unrelated tables, the no, probably not. If the polygon ID is in the CSV, then it's easy. If a centroid of the polygon is in the CSV, it's a bit harder, but not difficult.

Comment: If the Access records have an area field it might be possible to get many records to join on an area field, leaving less manual work.  I would add new fields to the Access table and polygon attribute table, starting with an integer field to make matches more likely, and calculate the existing area fields data into it.  Then try to do a join on the new integer fields and see how well it does.  If there are too many shared integer values try real fields with a precision of 1.  Or sort on the values in each & join by row#.  As a mismatch occurs, skip it, select the rest and repeat.